# Create file in bash + write content to it

Tags: macos, bash, shell

So I want to create a bash script, I know how to create the file but I don't know how to write to that new file.I want to write some php code to that file.

Can you guys give me some examples?

The bash script should:

1. Create a new file, eg: **myFile.php**
2. Write to **myFile.php** `<?php echo 'Hi'; ?>`

Comment: You want to edit a text file? You want to write PHP code for a certain purpose?

Comment: I want to create more template files for a certain php application and I want to create them all at once from the Terminal, is more easy this way :-)

Comment: `echo string > file`? `cat other-file > file`?

Comment: would probably make more sense if you describe your actual use case in detail in your question.

Comment: Updated please look at the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat > myFile.php <<- 'EOF'
<?php echo 'Hi'; ?>
EOF

printf "<?php echo 'Hi'; ?>\n" > myFile.php

echo "<?php echo 'Hi'; ?>" > myFile.php
```

A file is always created when a shell redirect directs to it. (The semantics of the word *redirection* are interesting here: actually the file *is* standard output, but that's a detail.) So if you change standard output to a file, and write to standard output, you're writing to that file. The file exists when you direct standard output to it.

Comment: Just out of curiocity : What's the difference between `<<EOF` & `<<- 'EOF'`? I am much used to 1st syntax..

Comment: adding the single quotes effectively single quotes the entire heredoc, so you don't have to escape all the dollar signs etc in your php code. The hyphen allows you to use tab characters (but **not** spaces) to indent the heredoc for readability